# Managing Spell-check Dictionary WPF

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

is possible to manage words inside RichTextBox/TextBox with spellcheck enable, I found this necesary cause some medical technicians are highlighted (not found in .net dictionary resource)

please advice if this feature is enable yet, thanks!

• C# -  Fx3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't control the spell checker dictionary.

A quick Google search will tell you they are "considering it for a future version".

Comment: now is confirmed, I Found that aswer before SP1 comes released, so thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

I understand this post is old but I wanted to let you know that the 4.0 framework now allows Custom Dictionaries for WPF TextBoxes and RichTextBoxes.  The implementation of this is easy as long as you avoid a few problem areas.  Please let me know if you have questions on how to do this.

Comment: I don't need this anymore, but just for reference to people insterested on this you can provide some links

Comment: Here is a link to my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/14840313/1987446
And here is a link to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries.aspx