# WPF 4.0 SpellCheck issue loading Custom Dictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

Has anyone used a custom dictionary into WPF 4.0?
I am having an issue getting the Custom Dictionaries to work in my WPF project.
I have been trying to follow the example msdn offers but have made no progress.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries.aspx

```
glossary.Definition.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Prog.Proj;component/dictionary.lex");
glossary.Definition.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(uri);
```

Due to the nature of my work sub folders have been renamed.

My .lex file is set as a resource file.

**EDIT**
I am able to get this to work only if I set it up in a separate button event after the page has already loaded.  It seems that something is preventing the 'Speller' property of CustomDictionariesSources to load until after a postback?  If anyone knows anything on this please post your insight.

**FINAL EDIT**
My desired text box was within a grid which had a enabled disabled flag that was set deep within the code.  Another link commented below talks towards this point.  Another issue faced is my page is rendered by parts depending on user selection.  To create consistent behavior I am loading my spellcheck as a last step each time my textbox would be loaded/re-loaded.

I created a context menut extension to allow users to either take a suggestion or add to a custom dictionary.  I am then submitting my custom dictionary into the registry based on current user.  I found this direction to be very user friendly and easy to implement.  To retrieve the items back I need to create a temporary file, pack the uri for that file then after loading the custom dictionary I deleted the file.

If this helps you implement your custom spell check or if you have questions please let me know!

Comment: If your `.lex` file is set as an embedded resource, why are you using a file path to access it? Try using a [`pack:` URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa970069.aspx) instead.

Comment: I tried that also.  If you have a working example of how to do this please let me know.

Comment: There is a working example of a Pack URI at the bottom of the article which you linked to, in your original question.

Comment: I really must not be explaining myself very well.  I have tried that one.  It did not work for me.  I even went as far as using a helper class in the code behind to rule out any issues with packing the URI the wrong way.  The original example does not work for me for some reason.  I am re-visiting the xaml version right now and still nothing.  I am however getting a little message that say my sys:Uri has no default constructor.

Comment: Indeed, I am having some trouble understanding the problem.  Please add some additional details to the question, such as what - exactly - isn't working, error messages, exceptions, etc.

Comment: When I go to my text box which has Spell Check enabled and is attempting to load my .lex file in either of the two examples on the link stated I AM able to see incorrectly spelled words but the words that are supposed to be ignored due to my custom dictionary are still viewed as incorrectly spelled.  I will add an edit with some more info.

Comment: In your Visual Studio project, where is the .lex file located?  You may not be providing the correct URI.  If your lex file is in a "resources" folder, then that folder needs to be added to the path.

Comment: I have moved the .lex file out of any sub folders and is now in the root directory of the program folder.

Comment: Looking further when I debug my Uri created byUri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/WPFCustomDictionary;component/dictionary.lex"); I get an exception which does not stop the program - The generic authority 'application:,,,' is not a valid dns name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI in your example is a Disk path to a folder on your C: drive.  If you want to access the lex file embedded as a resource within your application, you need to use a "[Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)."

Refer to the [article which you already linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4), for an example of a Pack URI being used to load a custom dictionary:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IList dictionaries = SpellCheck.GetCustomDictionaries(richTextBox1);

    // customwords2.lex is included as a resource file
    dictionaries.Add(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/WPFCustomDictionary;component/customwords2.lex"));
}
```

Comment: With more testing I found that this and the other example actually work IF I load the page select a different page and then come back.  I am currently trying to debug the problem but found some articles that talk about disabling then enabling spell check.  I will keep this post updated as I find out more.

Comment: It appears that there is a 'Speller' property hidden within CustomDictionaries which is null when the control is created but is not null when the control is re-loaded...  I cant find any documentation on this.

Comment: This is the correct answer as this is how the spell checker is supposed to work.  Please view my edits for additional problem solving tips as my issue was more extensive.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was fixed by changing the **Build Action** on my custom.lex file from *None* to *Resource*

[image]